# Incorrect Folder Pemissions on CIFS Mount

Tags: permissions, mount, windows-10, cifs, ubuntu-20.04

*(I'll start by acknowledging that there are lots of questions and answers out there about mount permissions and I have tried **a lot** of the proposed solutions without success.)*

I'm on Ubuntu 20.04 and I'm using CIFS to mount a directory from a Windows 10 machine. I'd like all directories and files to have write permission but my directories always have `555` permissions, while files have `755`.

Here's my current `/etc/fstab` entry:

```
//MY-WINDOWS-BOX/Share /home/someuser/share cifs credentials=/home/someuser/.share-credentials,iocharset=utf8,sec=ntlmssp,vers=3,uid=1000,gid=1000,nofail,noauto,x-systemd.automount,x-systemd.after=network-online.target 0 0
```

I've tried these options (along with others that I can't remember) and I get the same result:

- `file_mode=0755,dir_mode=0755,nounix`
- `noperm`
- `rw`

I've also verified that the Windows user in the credentials file has all permissions on the shared directory and its files/sub-directories.

Answer (score 0):

Apparently the issue was on the Windows side.

I logged in to my Windows box and verified again that both the NTFS permissions and the sharing permissions gave my user full access to the folder and its files/sub-directories. Even though everything looked correct, I decided to try running `chmod -R 755` from Git bash (which I happened to have installed) just to see what would happen. This resolved the issue.